# cts:near query not working with special character

Tags: xquery, marklogic

I have a document with element `<word>42 case § 100</word>`

I am searching for this using a near query since my requirement is to use it. This does not work when i use the below query,

```
cts:search(
  //word,
  cts:near-query(
    (
      cts:word-query("42",   ("case-insensitive","diacritic-insensitive","punctuation-insensitive","lang=en"), 1),
      cts:word-query("case", ("case-insensitive","diacritic-insensitive","punctuation-insensitive","lang=en"), 1),
      cts:word-query("§",    ("case-insensitive","diacritic-insensitive","punctuation-insensitive","lang=en"), 1),
      cts:word-query("1*",   ("case-insensitive","diacritic-insensitive","punctuation-insensitive","lang=en"), 1)
    ),
    2,
    ("ordered"),
    1
  )
)
```

Same works when I use `"§ 1*"` together instead of splitting them.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

§ is punctuation which is not included in the word index. You can change this by using custom tokenization overrides.  See [Search Developer's Guide](http://docs.marklogic.com/guide/search-dev/undefined/guide/search-dev/custom-tokenization) for more details.

Answer (score 0):

I think your distance (3rd param) is too small in this case. The distance is between *all* subqueries, so when looking for 4 ordered terms, you need a distance of 3.

HTH!

Comment: Changing the distance doesn't work. I have this working for other values instead of §

Comment: Doh, I must have looked up $ instead of §. I could be mistaken, but I think distance should be relevant here as well. Do you have positions enabled? Otherwise near-query behaves like and-query, when running unfiltered.